# DataInputStream.readInt() returns EOFException even if there is still data

Tags: java, json, file, eof, datainputstream

I am having lots of trouble reading a custom file in java.
The custom file format just consists of a so called "magic" byte array, the file format version and a gzipped json-string.

Writing the file works like a charm - reading on the other side works not as intended.
The EOFException gets thrown when I am trying to read the following data length.

I checked the produced file with a HEX editor, the data gets saved correctly. Something seems to go wrong while the DataInputStream tries to read the file.

The **read file** code:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

// Check file header
byte[] b = new byte[MAGIC.length];
in.read(b);

if (!Arrays.equals(b, MAGIC)) {
    throw new IOException("Invalid file format!");
}

short v = in.readShort();
if (v != VERSION) {
    throw new IOException("Old file version!");
}

// Read data
int length = in.readInt(); // <----- Throws the EOFException
byte[] data = new byte[length];
in.read(data, 0, length);

// Decompress GZIP data
ByteArrayInputStream bytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(new GZIPInputStream(bytes), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}); // mapper is the the jackson OptionMapper

bytes.close();
```

The **write file** code:

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

// File Header
out.write(MAGIC); // an 8 byte array (like new byte[] {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'}) to identify the file format
out.writeShort(VERSION); // a short (like 1)

// GZIP that stuff
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bytes);

mapper.writeValue(gzip, map);
gzip.close();

byte[] data = bytes.toByteArray();

out.writeInt(data.length);
out.write(data);

out.close();
```

I really hope that somebody can help me out with my problem (I am trying to solve this thing  for the whole day already)!

Regards

Comment: Are you flushing your output stream prior to trying to read from it?  If not, it's possible that your data.length and the data that follow it are simply stuck in a buffer somewhere.

Comment: I am not flushing anything, the code you see there is the full code I am using. I tried to use in.reset() but it only have me the "mark/reset not supported" IOException

Comment: Most likely you are not writing all the data you think you are either because you are not closing the file correct or not flushing the data.   You won't get an EOF unless there is no more data you can read.

Comment: I even tried to write a data-length 0 file (only contents were the MAGIC, VERSION and the 0) - same thing. Like I said, i checked the file multiple times with my HEX-Editor, the data got written correctly :(

Comment: Let's take GZIP out of the question: comment out the lines that read/write the actual data (along with the GZIP lines), and instead of writing data.length, just write a number (e.g. 42) and see if you can read that number in.  Also, the code you've shown us clearly isn't your full program; can you show us what calls the read file code and the write file code?  Are they just blocks in a single method, or two methods, or...?  Also, even if you're still having problems, dkatzel's right that you need to close the streams, so please update your code above with the new version that includes closing.

Comment: My application is a swing-application, the read file method is running in the main thread - the save file method in a swing worker (to display the save progress in a progress bar). I will try to comment out the gzip then ...

Comment: Tried it without any GZIP - no change, still hanging at in.readInt()

Comment: You say "hanging", but your earlier description was of an EOFException; is that still what's happening?  Also, this is just a shot in the dark, but is there any chance that your writing code and your reading code aren't referring to the same file, so your reading code is trying to read an old copy of the file somewhere?  And have you confirmed that the writing code actually changes the output file?  (Does the modification date change after writing?)

Comment: Seems like I found the bug - I had a joptionpane asking the user if he wants to open the recently opened project. weird thing is: the file referred to the same file that I opened when using the "open project" option. Manual open fixed it SOMEHOW (magic happens sometimes...). Thanks for the help anyways! *feels like a noob now*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are properly closing both the fileOutputStream and the GZIPOutputStream.

GZIPOutputStream requires that you call `close()` on it  when you are done to finish writing out the zipped data.  This will require you to hold onto a reference to the GZIPOutputStream.

Here is what I think the code should be

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

// File Header
out.write(MAGIC); // an 8 byte array (like new byte[] {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'}) to identify the file format
out.writeShort(VERSION); // a short (like 1)

// GZIP that stuff
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream zippedStream =new GZIPOutputStream(bytes)
mapper.writeValue(zippedStream, /* my data */); // mapper is the   Jackson ObjectMapper, my data is a Map<String, Object>


zippedStream.close();

byte[] data = bytes.toByteArray();

out.writeInt(data.length);
out.write(data);

out.close();
```

Comment: Problem still persisting - the EOFException gets thrown when reading the data.length integer from the file itself. But good hint with the finish and close functions!